# SQL list multiple Duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, matching

running a SQL query in access that is giving me matches where A = record 1, and B also = record 1 , C= record 2 and D E and F also = record 2.

I want my results to display (only max Value) 
B =record 1
F= record 2. ( this is a matching query)

basically i want to eliminate duplicates and select "distinct" does not seem to be working for me.

SELECT 
FEED_2.ID AS FEED_2_ID, 
FEED_3.field_ID, 
FEED_3.ID AS FEED_3_ID
FROM FEED_2 INNER JOIN FEED_3 ON FEED_2.[field_ID] = FEED_3.[field_ID]
order by FEED_3.ID

im getting results where feed 2 ID #1,3, and 5 all equal feed 3 - ID #1

i only want feed 2, #5 = feed 3 #1. no Dupes

sorry - hope that helps

Comment: Edit your question and include the query.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` operates on a per-row basis, so that the result set doesn't contain any pair of rows having the same value in every column.  Overall though, I don't understand what you're asking.  The current query would be helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark but, is something like this you are looking for?

```
SELECT max(Column_With_ABCDEF), Column_With_record from TABLE_NAME GROUP BY Column_With_record;
```

If this is not what you are asking for, please do edit your question with your table schema and/or the query you are using so we can help.

---------------- EDIT ----------------

Ok so you can try this:

```
Select     max(FEED_2_ID), field_ID , FEED_3_ID 
from       (
             SELECT FEED_2.ID AS FEED_2_ID, FEED_3.field_ID As field_ID, FEED_3.ID AS FEED_3_ID 
             FROM   FEED_2 INNER JOIN FEED_3
             ON     FEED_2.[field_ID] = FEED_3.[field_ID]
           ) 
 GROUP BY  FEED_3_ID, field_ID
 ORDER BY  FEED_3_ID
```

The main select is going to group the result from the subquery, that way you should not get duplicated values.

Hope this help

Comment: thank you. getting so many errors. still trying to disect this.